# SwiftUI 2 move file from Files app to documents directory with fileImporter

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm currently trying to import (audio) files from the system Files app to the app documents directory using the new `fileImporter`.

Selecting files works well but apparently, my `saveFile()` function doesn't save the file to the documents directory since listing all files with `listAllFiles()` always returns an empty array. If I try to play a sound with the local (documents) URL it just doesn't work at all.

Update: Seems to be a permission issue. Getting the error message `The file “XY.mp3” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.` using `try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: actualPath)`.

Update 2: Tried to do it with UIKit. Same issue as well.

Does somebody have an idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot for your help!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var importFiles = false
    @State var files = [URL]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                importFiles = true
            }, label: {Text("Import files")})
            .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                listAllFiles()
            }, label: {Text("List files")})
            .padding()
            
            Spacer()
            ForEach(files, id: \.self){ file in
                Text(file.lastPathComponent)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .fileImporter(
            isPresented: $importFiles, allowedContentTypes: [.audio],
                allowsMultipleSelection: false
            ) { result in
                do {
                    let selectedFiles = try result.get()
                    if(selectedFiles.count == 1){
                        files.append(saveFile(url: selectedFiles[0]))
                    }
                    else{
                        print("error")
                    }
                    
                } catch {
                    // Handle failure.
                    print("failed")
                }
            }
    }
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
}

func listAllFiles() {
    let documentsUrl = getDocumentsDirectory()

    do {
        let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        print(directoryContents)

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func saveFile (url: URL) -> URL {
    
        let fileData = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url)
        let fileName = url.lastPathComponent
        
        let actualPath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        do {
            try fileData?.write(to: actualPath, options: .atomic)
            print("success. origin: \(url) target: \(actualPath)")
        } catch {
            print("File could not be saved")
        }
    return actualPath
}
```

Comment: Lol, I'm trying to do this in the opposite direction. From Docs Dir to Files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a lot of research, I found out that including `CFURLStartAccessingSecurityScopedResource` and `CFURLStopAccessingSecurityScopedResource` to the `saveFile` function fixes the issue. However, I have absolutely no idea why. If anybody knows more, I'd be pleased to hear about it.

```
func saveFile (url: URL) {
    if (CFURLStartAccessingSecurityScopedResource(url as CFURL)) { // <- here
        
        let fileData = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url)
        let fileName = url.lastPathComponent
        
        let actualPath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        do {
            try fileData?.write(to: actualPath)
            if(fileData == nil){
                print("Permission error!")
            }
            else {
                print("Success.")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        CFURLStopAccessingSecurityScopedResource(url as CFURL) // <- and here
    }
    else {
        print("Permission error!")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for sharing, worked for me! My basic understanding from the [apple site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox) is that apps are sandboxed, meaning they can't just access everything on the phone, so you need to ask for permission to do so, and only while getting data.

Comment: @Josiah However, this actually seems to be a macOS method. It’s very confusing.